# Remove Duplicate Image From wx.StaticBitmap

Tags: python, bitmap, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I have a problem with `wx.StaticBitmap` when I `SetBitmap` in it, it shows the image but always duplicate the image: one as static background and one as the bitmap that I showed. Please see this screenshot -> [duplicate_image_wxstaticbitmap.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5mJ9.png)

This is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
from PIL import Image

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 440,514 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        sbSizer1 = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.StaticBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"COMPOSITE" ), wx.VERTICAL )

        self.composite_sb = wx.StaticBitmap( sbSizer1.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 400,400 ), 0 )
        sbSizer1.Add( self.composite_sb, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        bSizer1.Add( sbSizer1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.load_img_btn = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Load Image", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.load_img_btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        self.load_img_btn.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loadImage )

    def loadImage( self, event ):
        myPilImage = Image.open('result.tiff')
        myWxImage = wx.EmptyImage( myPilImage.size[0], myPilImage.size[1] )
        myWxImage.SetData( myPilImage.convert( 'RGB' ).tobytes() )  
        #myWxImage = myWxImage.Scale(400,400)   
        self.composite_sb.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(myWxImage))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame1(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What happens if you resize the frame (drag the frame border) slightly?

Comment: If i resize the frame it would impact the whole layout. I just wondering why it's duplicate the image is there any wrong on my code?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour (showing the bitmap on two different positions at the same time on MSW) is along the lines of [this wxwidgets trac ticket](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/4564#no1). Should be resolved, but seems still to be an issue.
This also seems to be coupled to the behaviour of the native MSW control, which will center the bitmap in the allocated space (and not put it into the upper left corner). If you are searching, there can more tickets be found regarding this issue.

A simple workaround, which fixes things for me on wxPython 3.0.2 (classic, MSW) is:

```
def loadImage( self, event ):
    # ...
    self.composite_sb.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(myWxImage))
    self.Layout()
```

Obviously `self.Layout()` forces the controls in the frame to "decide" where the contents should be drawn.